# Referencing my view object's `this` instance instead of the window's in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm referencing my self method(s) within my view object as this.removeThanksContainer which is fine normally,, but when I am inside my $.post() callback, the reference to `this` becomes the global window object and not my view….

```
    removeThanksContainer : function() {
        var $thanksContainer = $('#js-review-thanks');

        $thanksContainer.is(':visible') && $thanksContainer.remove();
    },

    getProductInfo : function(evt) {
        // local method
        var removeThanksContainer = this.removeThanksContainer;

        $.post(postURL, { product_id : productId }, function(data) {
            if (data) {
                removeThanksContainer();
            }
        }, 'json');
    }
```

So as a workaround I'm saving a reference to that method to a local variable within getProductInfo as `var removeThanksContainer = this.removeThanksContainer;` to access it within $.post(). Is this the best way to do this or is there a preferred/better method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also keep a reference to a `this` like

```
var that = this;
```

and call `that.removeThanksContainer();` in the `$.post` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
function myClass()
{
    var self=this;
    ....
    getProductInfo : function(evt) {
        // local method
        var removeThanksContainer = self.removeThanksContainer;
        // or call it directly without any reference you have kept above
        self.removeThanksContainer();
    }
}
```